# Assertion error on while installing with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages_distutils_hack_*init*_.py:17: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
warnings.warn(
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages_distutils_hack_*init*_.py:30: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pip.py", line 24424, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pip.py", line 139, in main
bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pip.py", line 120, in bootstrap
args = determine_pip_install_arguments()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pip.py", line 65, in determine_pip_install_arguments
import setuptools  # noqa
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init**.py", line 8, in 
import *distutils_hack.override  # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages_distutils_hack\override.py", line 1, in 
**import**('*distutils_hack').do_override()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages_distutils_hack_*init**.py", line 72, in do_override
ensure_local_distutils()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages_distutils_hack_*init**.py", line 59, in ensure_local_distutils
assert '_distutils' in core.**file**, core.**file**
AssertionError: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the error messages that comes while I try installing packages with pip. I'm looking for the assertion error that's shown in last, AssertionError: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py.